# How Can I Get The Value Of A Textfield From Database In Update Form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, yii

I'm using Yii framework Update form to get values from backend, I created a add/remove textfields feature in my form. I'm able to use the create form easily. But, I have a problem in update form.
Below is the code -

```
$(function () {
    var json = {
        "welcomeList": ["Thanks for coming", "Please select from the following list", "dwadwadsds"],
            "endList": ["Press come again", "Press 0"]
    };

    $.each(json.welcomeList, function (_, vv) {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" class=cnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="' + vv + '"placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo('#p_scents');
    });

    var scntDiv = $('#p_scents');
    var i = $('#p_scents p').size() + 1;

    $('#addScnt').live('click', function () {
        $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt_' + i + '" size="20" name="p_scnt_' + i + '" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="remScnt">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
        i++;
        return false;
    });

    $('#remScnt').live('click', function () {
        if (i > 2) {
            $(this).parents('p').remove();
            i--;
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

In the above code, I want to replace the hardcoded value of var json with the value from the database to the textfield. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, for example
DefaultController

```
public function actionIndex() {
    //Here you can get data from DB
    //and fill $result array, but I fill it manuallly

    $result = array(
        'welcomeList' => array(
            "Thanks for coming",
            "Please select from the following list",
            "dwadwadsds"
        ),
        'endList' => array(
            "Press come again",
            "Press 0"
        )
    );

    echo json_encode($result);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

Finally json hardcore in JS you can replace by this

```
var json = [];
$.getJSON( "/default", function( data ) {
    json = data;
});
```